# Download XQuartz into Digital Ocean

Tags: r, digital-ocean, rgl, xquartz

I want to download the following link into my digital ocean droplet so that I can install the package 'rgl' for R. Here is the link to XQuartz: https://www.xquartz.org/

How do I go about doing this? Do I need to use sudo code or is it easier than that?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Digital Ocean does [not have macOS images](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/), so XQuartz isn't going to help as it's macOS-specific.

Comment: ok thanks, good to know!